# Can I make parallel sub-directories under a mother-directory without change to that mother-directory?

Tags: terminal

I was learing basic terminal command these days.

I found that I can make parallel directories by add a space between them:

```
mkdir dir_a dir_b
```

But when I trying to make parallel directories under a mother-directory, this fails.

```
mkdir dir_a/dir_a_1 dir_a_2   
# Failed, the dir_a_2 is on top level
```

Is there a way that I can make parallel sub-directories under a mother-directory without change to that mother-directory (without cd method) ?

Comment: working perfectly fine on my ubuntu system! what is your problem? Can you please clearly explain what directory structure you want?

Comment: The second dir_a_2 is not under dir_a.

Comment: Obviously it is not under `dir_a` for that you will have to use `mkdir dir_a/dir_a_1 dir_a/dir_a_2`. When you use `mkdir test` your shell interprets it as `mkdir ./test` so the directory will be created in the current directory only!

Comment: I know I can do that, do you know a way through which I needn't to type dir_a twice to make two sub-directories at the same time?

Comment: In that case best way is to `cd` to that directory and then create sub-directories!

Comment: So I guess there is no short cut to realize my purpose, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each argument to `mkdir` is rooted in the current directory. The behavior your are seeing is intentional. There's no special treatment of the first argument to `mkdir`.

However, there are several options available to achieve the result you are looking for.

You could use a loop:

```
for f in dir_a_1 dir_a_2; do mkdir -p "dir_a/$f"; done
```

You could use `pushd`:

```
mkdir dir_a; pushd dir_a; mkdir dir_a_1 dir_a_2; popd
```

You could use `printf` and command substitution:

```
mkdir -p  $(printf 'dir_a/%s ' dir_a_1 dir_a_2)
```

You could use `printf` and xargs:

```
printf 'dir_a/%s ' dir_a_1 dir_a_2 | xargs mkdir -p
```

Any of these should work for you.